# How to populate UIPickeView from dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uipickerview

I have this pickerData:

```
var pickerData: (id: String, value: [String: String])?
```

when I tap on UITextField I do the next:

```
@IBAction func whoCanSee(_ sender: UITextField) {
    pickerData = (id: "viewOption", value: ["F": "Me and my friends", "M": "Only certain users", "E": "Every user"])

    sender.inputView = self.pickerView
}
```

and later in

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)
```

I'm trying to fetch values from `value` in my tuple as:

```
self.pickerData!.value.values[row]
```

but it returns me this error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, String>, String>' with an index of type 'Int'
```

I have tried also with `for...in` but in this keys obviously I get always the first element, as each time this block is calling again and again.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a dictionary so you cannot just give it an index. Firs

```
let arr = Array(self.pickerData!.value)
print(arr[row])
```